# How can I delete the photo after proccesing it?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-file-upload

I have two fields in my django model:

```
 class Staff(models.Model):

    photo = models.FileField(blank=True, null = True)
    encodings = JSONField()
```

I get the photo from form and after that using this photo get encodings. How can I delete the photo after proccesing it? I tried

```
self.photo = None or self.photo = ''
```

but in this case I get "The 'photo' attribute has no file associated with it"

Comment: Do you assign the photo attribute before you try to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You can import the `os` module and then do:

```
os.remove(path/to/photo)
```

Also, if you are only processing photos, you should use `ImageField` instead of `FileField` in my opinion.